# Warning: compiled but with compilation error in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am getting this warning in toad. so unable to use the procedure. i am creating a varray first.

```
CREATE or replace  TYPE notif_array AS VARRAY(100000) OF VARCHAR2(10);
```

Then i am creating a procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_notification_id
    ( personrole in varchar2, personid out notif_array )
is
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(personrole);

    select person_id into personid
    from   exp_role_person_mapping
    where  person_role = personrole;
exception
    when others then
        personid := null;
end;
```

then after that i am getting warning from toad

```
Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

Comment: Query the `user errors` view to see the actual problem. (Not sure if Toad supports `show errors`.)

Comment: @AlexPoole. tried. It shows "No errors."

Comment: Bring the cursor on to the procedure and press F4, popup window will open and go to the Errors tab.

Comment: It's `pl/sql ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected udt got char`. If You change `select person_id into ...` to `select person_id bulk collect into...` the procedure compiles.

Comment: Done. It says "PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR"

Comment: @PonderStibbons. Done. Thank you for your help

Comment: btw unless there is some business significance to the figure of 100000, I would use a normal nested table type rather than a varray. `create or replace type notif_array as table of varchar2(10);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way, in which you assign data to personid.

It is not a base data type, rather its a custom data type defined as per your requirement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_notification_id(personrole in varchar2,personid out notif_array)
is
CURSOR cur_temp(per_role varchar2)
IS
   select person_id from  exp_role_person_mapping where person_role=per_role;
   index NUMBER := 1;
begin
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(personrole);
   FOR datarecord in cur_temp(personrole)
   LOOP
       personid(index) := datarecord.person_id;
       index = index + 1;
   END LOOP;
exception when others then
   personid:=null;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

just add "bulk collect" in select statement. Thanks to  Ponder Stibbons

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_notification_id(personrole in varchar2,personid out notif_array)
is
begin
select person_id bulk collect  into personid from  exp_role_person_mapping where person_role=personrole;
exception when others then
personid:=null;
end;
```